# Passing a variable as argument to selenium find_element function instead of hardcoded argument results in a InvalidArgumentException

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

### Context

I am using selenium with python and trying to separate my `PageObjects` from my code following the [official selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html#locators) and I get an error which I don't understand:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class MainPageLocators(object):
    """A class for main page locators. All main page locators should come here"""
    GO_BUTTON = (By.ID, 'submit')
```

Doing it like above gives me an `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: expected value at line 1 column 11` error.

### Reproducing

I reproduced the error using the Google homepage:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


def test():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    element = (By.NAME, "btnK")
    driver.find_element(element)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    test()
  File "test.py", line 10, in test
    driver.find_element(element)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: expected value at line 1 column 11
```

Interestingly passing directly passing the argument in the find_element function as follow works fine.

```
def test():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')

    element = ()
    driver.find_element(By.NAME, "btnK")
```

### Environment

OS: Windows 10
Browser: Firefox
Browser version: 77.0.1
Browser Driver version: GeckoDriver 0.26
Language Bindings version: Python 3.6 , python-selenium 3.141.0
Selenium Grid version (if applicable):

### GeckoDriver logs

```
1593341659616   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\xxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofileNZPCZw"
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1593341663463   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 62786
1593341663826   Marionette  WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/NetworkGeolocationProvider.jsm, line 555: TypeError: xhr.response.location is undefined
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "btnK")
```

and

```
args = (By.NAME, "btnK")
driver.find_element(args)
```

is that the first version sends two arguments, and the second version sends one argument (a tuple).

Use the `*` operator to "unpack" the arguments:

```
args = (By.NAME, "btnK")
driver.find_element(*args)
```